# How do I create a CKRecord in a custom zone without having to specify a record name?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I am using the following code to create a `CKRecord` in a custom private `CKRecordZone`:

```
let noteZoneID = CKRecordZone.ID(zoneName: CloudKitManager.noteZoneName,
                                 ownerName: CKCurrentUserDefaultName)
return CKRecord(recordType: Note.recordType, zoneID: noteZoneID)
```

This seems to work just fine, but I am getting a warning: `'init(recordType:zoneID:)' is deprecated: Use init(recordType:recordID:) + CKRecord.ID(zoneID:) instead`

If I used those methods instead, I think I would have to do something like:

```
let noteZoneID = CKRecordZone.ID(zoneName: CloudKitManager.noteZoneName,
                                 ownerName: CKCurrentUserDefaultName)
let recordID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: "UniqueRecordName", zoneID: noteZoneID)
return CKRecord(recordType: Note.recordType, recordID: recordID)
```

My problem with this method is that suddenly I am responsible for creating a unique `recordName`, and I don't understand why that is the case. Is there an alternate way of creating a record that removes that responsibility? Is there a specific reason why my app code should come up with the `recordName`?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to bypass this for a custom zone. If you don't want to assign a `recordName` value, you can pass it a `UUID().uuidString`.

> Record ID objects are normally created automatically when you create a
>   new record, but [...] **you must create record ID objects when you
>   want to save a record in a zone other than the default zone.**
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord/id